# Dependencies for OPUS are not satisfiable on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, permissions, dependencies

I need to install OPUS (a spectroscopy software by Brucker) on Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. Unfortunatelly, Brucker has only packaged it for Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit. 
I downloaded it anyway and tried to install it with Gdebi but I got:

> Dependency is not satisfiable: libboost-date-time1.40.0 (>= 1.40.0-1)

Since the package is apparently not available in the backport rep, should I download it manually or will it break anything?

(On a side note, I wonder if that's only the first of a series of dependency problems...)

- Edit: The OPUS package is in https://www.bruker.com/powermail/optics/opus-download-request.html, but it's only available after one has filled the form.
- Edit 2: Adding architecture i386 doesn't help either:

  ```
  dpkg --add-architecture i386 
  apt-get update 
  gdebi libboost-date-time1.40.0_1.40.0-4ubuntu4_i386.deb 
  gdebi opus_7.0.122.1124-1_i386.Ubuntu1004LTS.deb
  ```

Leads to the same error.

- Edit 3: Back to the shell scenario: The launcher contains following lines:

  ```
  opus_user_group="${OPUS_USER_GROUP:-opus}"  
  sg_bin="$(which sg)"  
  if [ -n "${sg_bin}" ]; then  
   cmdline_cmd_change_group="${sg_bin} ${opus_user_group} -c"  
  fi
  ```

So OPUS creates its own group, right? Just to check, I set my home to 777 but again it says

> Your user/group configuration does not allow write access to the main work directory as required, ...aborting

like mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: You mean downloading `libboost-date-time` manually? You can try, but your assumption is correct. This can be the first of series of dependency problems

Comment: The `libboost-date-time1.58.0` package is available in Xenial, but since the version is part of the package name, it probably doesn't help unless you try to build OPUS from source and modify that dependency. Personally I'd try to install the Lucid version manually.

Comment: If you can, include the download page link into the question by editing it

Comment: I recommend trying with the .sh installer instead of the .deb file. Once you downloaded it, make it executable (see questions about installing from .sh files) and install it in your home directory. You have to accept a license agreement. Once installed, go to the installed folder -> bin folder and then make the `opus_launcher` executable and double click it to run. Then edit the question about the result (whether it is successful or any errors thrown) (Since you can't comment yet)

Comment: @AnwarShah I did as you suggested but ran the launcher from the terminal. Following error pops up: _Your user/group configuration does not allow write access to the main work directory as required, ...aborting_ , although I have set the access on my home to 775 (apparently I can comment after all)

Comment: Ah! That's the same error I was shown :( Need to dig further to see if it works in 32bit 16.04.

Comment: In the mean time, I tried installing libboost-date-time1.40.0_1.40.0-4ubuntu4_amd64.deb manually and then opus, but gdebi stills gives the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution by OP**

Finally got OPUS (kind of) running. Here's how:
I read the dependencies from the OPUS .deb file with

```
dpkg -f opus_7.0.122.1124-1_i386.Ubuntu1004LTS.deb
```

getting a list of about 25 needed packages. Some of them were obsolete, in which case I downloaded their i386 version from Launchpad and installed them and with gdebi, manually satisfying their dependencies.
Others could be managed with apt-get:

```
apt-get install xxx:i386
```

Finally, I used the .sh file to install OPUS and in line

```
opus_user_group="${OPUS_USER_GROUP:-opus}"
```

of the launcher I replaced 'opus' with my group name. This last step isn't pretty, but it works.
Obviously that's not the end of it. I'm now facing a thousand new problems when trying to actually use the programme, but they're beyond the scope of this site.